# WPF: multi monitor programming

Tags: c#, wpf, multiple-monitors

I'm using `WPF` in `C#`

I want to begin with multi monitor programming, that mean the app will display on many monitors with different views.

I have searched on internet, and I have got the approach that using `Screen.AllScreens[]`, however I have the following question

There are many ways to connect many monitor to PC

Case 1: In Laptop: 1 Laptop's Screen, 1 Screen connect to VGA port, 1 Screen connect to HDMI port...

Case 2: In Desktop: Many Screens connect to VGA card that support multi output

Case 3: Many Screens connect to Hub HDMI or Hub VGA, and the Hub connect to PC

My question is, `Screen.AllScreens[]` support for which case?

And there are any other way, that support all of case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It should show the same as the number of logical screens you have set up in your display settings, regardless of how they are connected.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Thanks for your reply, you have tried it before?

Comment: Yes, many times, even with a USB monitor.

Comment: There seems to be a cautionary note on `Screen.AllScreens` in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5020623/791010) - it may not report the correct screens if the screens change while your program is running, and after you've called it for the first time.

Comment: @RonBeyer: I will try to use it, many thanks!

Comment: @JamesThorpe: I will test that case, thank you!

Comment: @RonBeyer: In case 3, I hear someone tell that I cannot with the hub, before the hub cannot output with different views. You tested with this case? and which model of Hub that you tested.

Comment: I used a Matrox TripleHead2Go, but like I said, if in the display settings it *looks* like one monitor, then only one monitor will show up. If the hub just makes one giant monitor out of many monitors, then its logically only a single monitor.

Comment: @RonBeyer: thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

`Screens.AllScreens[]` is a WinForms method, if I'm not mistaken, but yes this supports all of your cases (as far as I know). If I remember correctly, that WinForms method initialized the static property on application startup and it wouldn't update if the screens were changed during runtime.

As you are dealing with WPF, I would avoid WinForms alltogether. Instead write your own `Screens` wrapper that p/invokes the Win32 API. Also, hook up an event handler to notify you when display settings change, for example:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += new EventHandler(this.SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged);
```

This is the wrapper I use:

```
/// <summary>
/// This class deals with monitors.
/// </summary>
internal static class Monitors
{
    private static List<Monitors.Screen> Screens = null;

    internal static List<Monitors.Screen> GetScreens()
    {
        Monitors.Screens = new List<Monitors.Screen>();

        var handler = new NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.EnumMonitorsDelegate(Monitors.MonitorEnumProc);
        NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, handler, IntPtr.Zero); // should be sequential

        return Monitors.Screens;
    }

    private static bool MonitorEnumProc(IntPtr hMonitor, IntPtr hdcMonitor, NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.RECT rect, IntPtr dwData)
    {
        NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.MONITORINFO mi = new NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.MONITORINFO();

        if (NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, mi))
        {
            Monitors.Screens.Add(new Monitors.Screen(
                (mi.dwFlags & 1) == 1, // 1 = primary monitor
                mi.rcMonitor.Left, 
                mi.rcMonitor.Top, 
                Math.Abs(mi.rcMonitor.Right - mi.rcMonitor.Left), 
                Math.Abs(mi.rcMonitor.Bottom - mi.rcMonitor.Top)));
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents a display device on a single system.
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class Screen
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the Screen class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="primary">A value indicating whether the display is the primary screen.</param>
        /// <param name="x">The display's top corner X value.</param>
        /// <param name="y">The display's top corner Y value.</param>
        /// <param name="w">The width of the display.</param>
        /// <param name="h">The height of the display.</param>
        internal Screen(bool primary, int x, int y, int w, int h)
        {
            this.IsPrimary = primary;
            this.TopX = x;
            this.TopY = y;
            this.Width = w;
            this.Height = h;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a value indicating whether the display device is the primary monitor.
        /// </summary>
        internal bool IsPrimary { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the display's top corner X value.
        /// </summary>
        internal int TopX { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the display's top corner Y value.
        /// </summary>
        internal int TopY { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the width of the display.
        /// </summary>
        internal int Width { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the height of the display.
        /// </summary>
        internal int Height { get; private set; }
    }
}

internal static class NativeMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Methods for retrieving display devices.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class DisplayDevicesMethods
    {
        internal delegate bool EnumMonitorsDelegate(IntPtr hMonitor, IntPtr hdcMonitor, NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.RECT rect, IntPtr dwData);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool EnumDisplayMonitors(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr lprcClip, EnumMonitorsDelegate lpfnEnum, IntPtr dwData);

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves information about a display monitor.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hmonitor">A handle to the display monitor of interest.</param>
        /// <param name="info">A pointer to a MONITORINFO or MONITORINFOEX structure that receives information about the specified display monitor.</param>
        /// <returns>If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool GetMonitorInfo(IntPtr hmonitor, [In, Out] NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.MONITORINFO info);

        /// <summary>
        /// The RECT structure defines the coordinates of the upper-left and lower-right corners of a rectangle.
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;
            public int Top;
            public int Right;
            public int Bottom;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The MONITORINFO structure contains information about a display monitor.
        /// </summary>
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 4)]
        internal class MONITORINFO
        {
            internal int cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.MONITORINFO));
            internal NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.RECT rcMonitor = new NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.RECT();
            internal NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.RECT rcWork = new NativeMethods.DisplayDevicesMethods.RECT();
            internal int dwFlags;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Works nicely