# Position to center screen in triple monitor setup with extended view

Tags: c#, wpf, multiple-monitors

I have three monitors/screens of different sizes/resolutions setup as an extended view, all wired to the same NVIDIA graphic card. And from left to right:

1. **Screen#0**: 2400*1080
2. **Screen#1**: 1920x1080
3. **Screen#2**: 1920*1080

My application has three separate Windows, where I respectively position each Window to the corresponding monitor/screen with the following code

```
window00.Left = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea.Left;
window01.Left = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Left;
window02.Left = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens[2].WorkingArea.Left;

window00.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
window01.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
window02.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

I only get the 3rd windows (window02) position to the right most screen properly (Screen#02), but both the 1st and 2nd windows (window00 & window01) stack and maximized to the first screen (Screen#00), leaving the middle Screen#01 empty displaying the background desktop environment, regardless if I set WindowsState.Maximized or Normal.

Even if I workaround the problem through offsetting window01 position by the width of Screen#00 to get all three windows position properly to their corresponding screens, if I maximize Windows.State, window01 still jumps back to Screen#00.

Why is this happening and why does the window not position or maximized to its WorkingArea it assigned to? Could it be due to WPF application using Forms properties?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230151/how-to-force-wpf-startup-window-to-specific-screen)?

Comment: Yes in fact I also tried all Normal with windows size smaller than screen size just to test out but still Screen 0 and 1 seems to overlap on the left while Screen 2 separately on the right, as if the  Screen 1 does not exist